# spring @JmsListener non compile time replacement

Tags: spring, jms, spring-jms

Looking for some alternative JMS `destination` configuration. The most common way of configuring `destination` and listener is by using annotation.

```
@JmsListener(destination = destination)
public void fetchMessage(final Message message) {
```

However, `destination` property have to be provided during the compile time. How to quickly replace it using some property which will be resolved only during runtime?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a property placeholder for the destination

```
@JmsListener(destination = "${queue.name}")
```

Then set the property in some property source available to the application (e.g. `application.properties` or `application.yml` for a boot app, or a system property `-Dqueue.name=foo` for any app).